# process two input pins to process using Directshow Filter

Tags: filter, switch-statement, directshow

I am working on directshow filters and looking for the filter that take two input pins with one out put 
Main idea is i want to write switch filter that can swith from one input pin to another input pin Please help me i am  new in directshow filters

Answer (score 1):

No standard filter of this kind. Write your own or look for third party solution. You request quite specific functionality (most likely you would have to make more assumptions as for its operation), so you would probably have to end up with your own custom filter.

Comment: i tried to write my own filter but won't be able.... plz help me to start this plzzz////////////